# Nutch problem: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, tomcat, cygwin, nutch

I'm trying to run Nutch on my Windows machine. I have Nutch, Java, Tomcat, and Cygwin installed. When I try to run the crawl command in Cygwin, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/nutch/crawl/Crawl
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main"
```

My Java is a bit rusty, but this seems to be telling me that the `Crawl` class doesn't exist. If this is the case, how do I go about finding it -- and making sure my system is aware of its existence?

Comment: Figured it out. I should have downloaded the bin, not the src.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must add the nutch jar to your classpath. [See here how](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/classpath.html)

It appears that the nutch distribution does not ship with a jar. You have to build it yourself using the ant `build.xml`. Type `ant jar` in the nutch directory (if you have ant installed), and it will make the jar.

Comment: I did a search for crawl.jar on my system. I did not find it. Did I do something wrong along the way?

Comment: it is the nutch jar which contains the crawl class.

Comment: And I just did a search for nutch.jar. It's also not found. I've double check in the Nutch folder. It's not there. What am I doing wrong? And why is this so hard?

Comment: you said you have Nutch.. so you don't have it ? Download it and you'll have it ;)

Comment: I have the latest version of Nutch. I can see the files in my system. There is no Nutch.jar.

Answer (score 2):

for nutch-1.4, running

```
ant job
```

from within the nutch directory, and then moving the resulting nutch-*.job file from the build subdirectory into the src subdirectory, did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

The JVM is telling you that it cannot find the `Crawl` class.  This is most likely because the command line arguments being passed to the `java` command are not specifying the correct classpath.  (The classpath is a search path used when searching for classes, and is typically set on the command line or using the CLASSPATH environment variable.)

Answer (score 0):

What version are you using though ? Because some version include the .jar, however the recent ones like 1.2 does not and there is a warning somewhere telling you that you must build it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how Old it is, I had the same problems with nutch 1.4, well my solution:

- set NUTCH_JAVA_HOME to the java home folder
- set NUTCH_HOME
- set JAVA_HOME
- set CLASSPATH to include all required jar files

open nutch in bin
and

1. change cygwin manually to true
2. DELETE the native folder from the lib folder

99% Crawl should output something familiar.